# Regular Expression in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to capture a word which appears after a pattern. For example if the string under consideration is "abc def ghi" and I need to return the next word after "def" (if one exists). In this case it is "ghi".
Can someone please tell me what should be the regex in python for this? We can assume that we are dealing with space separated strings.
For "abc def ghi jkl def pqr", it should return ['ghi', 'pqr'].

Comment: you need to give a more concrete example. is space separated words the only kind of string that you will be processing?

Comment: Yes, we can assume that we are dealing with space separated strings.

Comment: so you are always looking for word after "def"? or it can be anything?

Comment: I am always looking for "def". I need to find the next word that comes after "def". If the test string that we are considering is "abc def ghi pqr", it should return "ghi". I hope I am clear now. Thanks.

Comment: `re.search(r"def\s+(\w+)", "abc def ghi")`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def\s+(\w+)?
```

Next word after 'def' comes in capture group 1

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/JSTpKG/3)

Python Sample:

```
import re

regex = r"def\s+(\w+)?"

test_str = "abasdf asdfklj asdflkj; asdf def 1 asdf asdf def pqrdss"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        print (match.group(groupNum))
```

[Run it here](https://repl.it/EQ7h/0)

Comment: probably because you included the whitespace in the group

Comment: @UnderWood have you found a solutio for this yet ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
import re
results = re.findall('def\s*(\w+)','def gdi def hrs')
```

to

Comment: But if the string is "abc def ghi pqr", wouldn't this return "ghi pqr"?

Comment: @UnderWood -  changed to \w so it would not catch a space after the next word

Comment: For "abc def ghi jkl def pqr", it is returning only "pqr". How do I get both "ghi" and "pqr"?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @UnderWood - I've removed the .* in the start so it will catch more *def*s

Answer (score 0):

You should use a combination of lookbehind and non-capturing group for this.

`(?<=def)(?:\s)(\w+)`

This will only look for tokens that are preceded by `def`, have a space (but won't capture it) and then capture the "words" (numbers + letters) after that space.

See it in action with explanations here: https://regex101.com/r/jrkMor/1

```
import re

string = 'abc def ghi jkl def pqr'
print(re.findall(r'(?<=def)(?:\s)(\w+)', string))
>> ['ghi', 'pqr']
```